# SVG paths not showing after upgrade to fabric version 1.5.0

Tags: fabricjs

See this fiddle.  The arc is visible with fabric 1.4.0 but not when the library is changed to 1.5.0.

https://jsfiddle.net/ex5s9mx9/2/

The relevant code is

```
  function makeArcPath(path, lineColor)
  {
    var p = new fabric.Path(path, 
    {
        stroke: lineColor,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        fill: false
    });
    return p;
  };

  function circularArcPath(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle)
  {
      var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
      var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

      var anglediff = startAngle - endAngle;
      var arcSweep = ((anglediff > 0 && anglediff < 180) || (anglediff < -180)) ? 0 : 1;

      var d = [["M", start.x, start.y], ["A", radius, radius, 0, 0, arcSweep, end.x, end.y]];

      return d;
  }
```

I have looked at the arc object with the debugger in both cases, and all fields are the same.

I'd be very grateful for any pointers.

Thanks.

Edit: If I append ["M", 0, 0] to the end of the path, then the arc does appear!

Edit 2: In the fiddle, when I first make my arc it has radius 0, but this is updated when it is moved by calling

```
c.arc.set('path', circularArcPath(c.left, c.top, 30, a1, a2));
```

However, if I use a non-zero radius right from the start, the problem disappears, so I think it must be something about the initial zero radius.

Comment: could you evaluate the possibility of open a bug? https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues

Comment: it may have something to do with arc to beizer and caching. i will check it.